# When talking about the rolling of an object (such as a wheel) what is the difference between sliding and slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, terminology

My question is rather simple.

Concerning with the rolling motion, what is the difference between slide and slip?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  Generally they can describe the same thing, with different implications.

Comment: By any chance do you mean pure rolling vs rolling with slipping?

Comment: Yes I do, I know what is the difference between pure rolling and rolling with slipping is, but in this setting I cannot distinguish between slipping and sliding

Comment: I don't think there is a formal/strict/professional/accepted physics-vocabulary distinction assigned to these two words in the context of a rolling wheel. Consider definitions at https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slide for Synonyms: slide, slip, skid.  "These verbs mean to move smoothly and continuously, often over a slippery surface. Slide usually implies rapid easy movement without loss of contact with the surface. Slip is most often applied to accidental sliding resulting in loss of balance or foothold.  Skid implies an uncontrolled, often sideways sliding caused by a lack of traction."